How to get Name YASEEN from table having one column with Alphabet in SQL Server
Example: TABLE Test_YY (str_Col char(1))
TABLE : **Test_YY **
COLUMN **str_Col ** values are:
Y,
A,
S,
E,
E,
N


Result: YASEEN

create table Test_YY (str_table char(10))

insert into  Test_YY
select 'Y'
UNION ALL
select 'A'
UNION ALL
select 'S'
UNION ALL
select 'E'
UNION ALL
select 'E'
UNION ALL
select 'N'

Result should be: YASEEN

You need an ORDER BY to make sure the rows are returned in the desired order. I.e you need another column for that.

If only those rows are in your table its just enough to do it by using STRING_AGG, depending on the database you do it on, the string_agg function might be there or not. You could do it like that:
SELECT STRING_AGG(str_Col, '') AS aggregated_string
FROM Test_YY;

Ofcourse, have in mind that it will connect all the rows from table- maybe you should group by some other column, or use WHERE clause to filter the rows that you need to be aggregated.

When using STRING_AGG(), be sure to include the WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ...) clause.  As jarlh pointed out in an earlier comment, you will need another column for that. SQL Server tables do not have an implicit order, and the order of concatenation for STRING_AGG() is undefined, unless an explicit order is defined. What may seem to work for small data sets might not work when the data is scaled up.
